# form validation for empty radio input, empty text input and highest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm not confident with JS. I need to check different things to prevent a form being submitted if:

input radio "colorT" and "colorB" are empty

input text field "length" and "height" are empty

input field "height" is over "400".

How is it possible?

```
<form name="tapform" method="post" action="">
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="181"  id="181" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="151"  id="151" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="110"  id="110" /></p>
<br />
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8309"  id="8309" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8305"  id="8305" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8313"  id="8313" /></p>
<p>LENGTH:</p>
<input type="text" name="length" />
<p>HEIGHT (max 400):</p>
<input type="text" name="height" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
```

EDIT: Thx. I try to be more clear: user must not be able to send the form if something is missing or if the Height field is more than 400. Something like this (or a easier way, if possible):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTap(){
        if (document.tapform.colorT.checked==""){
            alert("Alert! ColorT is empty");
            return false;
            }
        else if (document.tapform.colorB.checked==""){
            alert("Alert! ColorB is empty");
            return false;
            }
        else if (document.tapform.length.value==""){
            alert("Alert! Length is empty");
            return false;
            }
        else if (document.tapform.height.value==""){
            alert("Alert! Height is empty");
            return false;
            }
        else if (document.tapform.height.value>"400"){
            alert("Alert! Height is more than 400");
            return false;
            }
        else {
            return true;
        }               

        }       
</script>

<form name="tapform" method="post" action="" onsubmit = "return checkTap()" >
```

Comment: Yes it's possible but I get the feeling that's not actually the question here. Consider editing your question to provide a clear problem statement with the expected behaviour clearly outlined. It would also help if you included an example of what you've tried so far, I only see some HTML, no Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a plugin such as [jqueryvalidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for this. Using a plugin, the required changes are trivial. Note that the plugin will automatically stop submission if the form is not validated.

```js
$("#myform").validate();
```

```css
#myform label.error {
    margin-left: 10px;
 width: auto;
 display: inline;
    color:red;
    padding:4px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    box-shadow: 0  0 3px rgba(255,0,0,0.5); 
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="tapform" method="post" action="">
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="181"  id="181" required/></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="151"  id="151" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorT" value="110"  id="110" /></p>
<br />
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8309"  id="8309" required/></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8305"  id="8305" /></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="colorB" value="8313"  id="8313" /></p>
<p>LENGTH:</p>
<input type="text" name="length" required/>
<p>HEIGHT (max 400):</p>
<input type="text" name="height" required min="1" max="400"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
```

**Just don't forget to include**

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**and**

`<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

**Screenshot showing max value of 400 working as expected:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, except for maximun value that does'nt work: the form is submitted also if "height" is more than 400. I read the documentation and tested different ways but so far I haven't found a solution.
If I can't make it, I'll check it only in server-side.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the input to `<input type="text" name="height" required min="1" max="400"/>` ? It works for me in my example. If I put in 666 for example, I get the message  `Please enter a value less than or equal to 400.`  and the form is not submitted, see the screenshot I added above.

Comment: Yes I did it, but it doesn't work. But if I set "required" and "max:40" directly into the jQ it works fine: 
$( "#myform" ).validate({ rules: { colorT: "required", colorB: "required", length: "required", height: { required: true, max: 400 } } });

Comment: Strange, glad it works though. Out of curiosity, what browser are you using?

Comment: Strange indeed. I tested with firefox, chrome, ie, opera and safari. I can't explain. Anyway, i found a solution so thaks again :)